# How to get data from a gidview to jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am having `gridview` showing data from database such as

```
ProductID   ProductName      Price
----------------------------------
A00001      Apple            10.00      ADDTOCART
```

The *ADDTOCART* is a button.

```
GridViewRow gr = ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);

string itemId = gr.Cells[0].Text.Trim();
```

These are the code I use for codebehind to get the *ProductID* when click on *ADDTOCART*

Need assist for the code which can let the variable I declared in Jquery to get the *ProductID* like what the codebehind do when I click the *ADDTOCART* button.

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
        
        var name = "The name";//$("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value; //get the data.
        var id = "The id";//$("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>")[0].value; //get the data.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCurrentTime", //the url and method name of the webmethod
            data: "{ name: '" + name + "', id: '" + id + "' }", //pass in 2 data.
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) { //fixed
            alert(response.d);
        }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) { //fetching object come out, object inside got name and id, need to specific which data you want by obj.id/obj.name
        var obj = response.d;  //fetching the webmethod
        alert(obj.id + "" + obj.name) //display the return
        $('#trycart').append("<li>" + obj.id + "</li>");
        $('#cart').append("<tr><td>" + obj.id + "</td><td>" + obj.name +"</td></tr>"); //access the table id=cart, add in the data comeback from webmethod.
    }
```

I need assist to have the var name to have the product name, and var id to have the id when I click ADDTOCART.

Comment: When this method "ShowCurrentTime" gets called ? On button click ?

Comment: yes, on buttonclick, the button ADDTOCART

Comment: How did you attached the event handler of addtocart button to the JavaScript method? In the ShowCurrentTime method you need to get hold of the button which is clicked and then find the textboxes in the same TR of the button and use their valued as if and name.

Answer (score 1):

The element name and selectors can be manipulated by looking at the Dom.

In the button onclick pass this as parameter

```
function ShowCurrentTime(element)
{

var name = $(element).closest("tr").find("input[id*='txtUserName']").val();
    var id = $(element).closest("tr").find("input[id*='TextBox1']").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCurrentTime", //the url and method name of the webmethod
        data: "{ name: '" + name + "', id: '" + id + "' }", //pass in 2 data.
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) { //fixed
        alert(response.d);
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Your data from database is in your C# application, which is on your server side. The code above are jquery/javascript, which is on your client side.

It's very important to know the difference on server side and client side. Basically say, everything you can see from "view source" from browser, are client side, otherwise, on server side.

So go back to your question, you can build html with data from database in your c# application, or build json data object, and in turn use it in jquery.

Hope helps